# ios how to add pictures to photolibrary

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

i wrote ipad programs in mac using ios, and user imagepickercontroller access photolibrary,but it is empty, so i want to add some photos into it, please tell me, thx

Answer (score 2):

1. open any photos in safari in iphone simulator (by draging or by searching on google photos).
2. click and hold mouse left button (if its with buttons).
3. you will get the option to save the pic.
4. press the save button if you want to save that image and then open the photo library to see if the photo is added to photo library.

if you dont follow this then let me know.